# Flutter - URL Launcher Link widget buttons not showing on target: LinkTarget.self

Tags: flutter

I open a web page in the application using the url launcher - Link widget, but these buttons are not visible.

[This buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxBPO.png)

[My codes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/33bqn.png)